# Prevent React dev tools from changing props/state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-devtools

Is there a way to prevent any prop/state change from front-end on production?

I tried following but it completely disables the dev tools:

```
if (typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'object') {
  for (let [ key, value ] of Object.entries(
    window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__
  )) {
     window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__[key] =
       typeof value === 'function' ? () => {} : null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Encrypt it? I mean, once stuff is on the client (e.g., browser), it's pretty much out of your hands.

Comment: Because you need the devtools to modify anything on the frontend... Once you have the source code served to the browser, non much can be done compadre.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following bit of code in my Meteor application that uses React 16.3 as the UI library.

The `window.__ALLOW_REACT_DEVTOOLS__` is just a flag I set in the SSR html sent from the server because this line of code needs to preclude any React code, and I need it before `process.env` is available in the browser. On the server I set that value to false in production.

```
<script>
  if (
    !window.__ALLOW_REACT_DEVTOOLS__ &&
    window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ &&
    typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === "object"
  ) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__)) {
      window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__[key] = typeof value == "function" ? ()=>{} : null;
    }
  }

  delete window.__ALLOW_REACT_DEVTOOLS__;
</script>
```

The key to making this work is that it is loaded BEFORE React.

This will completely disable React-Devtools. When you click on the devtools tab it will just say *'Looking for React...'*.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found a way to keep even that function from getting injected/involved.

I just changed the disabler code to this:

// disable react-dev-tools for this project

```
 if (typeof window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === "object") {
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__)) {
            window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__[key] = typeof value == "function" ? ()=>{} : null;
        }
    }
```